# $\sum_n^\infty u_n$ converges and $\sum_n^\infty nu_n^2$ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let series $\sum_n^\infty u_n$ with $u_n=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{n^{3/4}} & \text{if } \exists p\in\mathbb{N}^*:n=p^2\\[6pt] 
\dfrac 1 {n^2} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Prove that: $\sum_n^\infty u_n$ converges and $\sum_n^\infty nu_n^2$ diverges

I don't know how to resolve this problem. Could you give me some hints?

Comment: The sum of the inverses of the primes diverges. Presumably you've covered this result.

Comment: Have you showed the convergence part? It is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Convergence:

\begin{align*}
\sum u_n &= \sum_{n=p^2} u_n + \sum_{n\neq p^2} u_n \\
&=\sum_{p} \frac1{p^{3/2}} + \sum_{n\neq p^2} \frac1{n^2} < \infty \\
\end{align*}

Divergence:

\begin{align*}
\sum nu_n^2 &> \sum_{n=p^2} nu_n^2\\
& = \sum_{p} p^2\frac1{p^3}\\
& = \sum_{p} \frac1{p}\\
\end{align*}
which is divergent as Andrés E. Caicedo mentioned in comments. [(wiki link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes)

Answer (score 0):

For convergence prove each part converges separately. P test.

For divergence one part diverges by p test.

Comment: It would be helpful if you made your answer a tad more detailed.

Comment: OP had asked for hints. So I didn't give a detailed answer